# Write PUNICODE_STRING to file, got garbage data

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I'm trying to write two PUNICODE_STRING structure to file, but the data written is invalid, any ideas?

(The data1 is `123` and data2 is `456` in this case)

```
DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
WCHAR buffer[1024];
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(L"c:\\log.txt", FILE_APPEND_DATA, 0, NULL, 
    OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
    wsprintf(buffer, L"%s :: %s\r\n", Data1->Buffer, Data2->Buffer);

    WriteFile(hFile, buffer, wcslen(buffer), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
    CloseHandle(hFile);
}
```

Comment: _but the data written is invalid_ Invalid, _how_? What, exactly, is written to the file?

Comment: `buffer, wcslen(buffer)` - already error - need size in bytes, not in symbols - use `wcslen(buffer) * sizeof(WCHAR)`, also for format `UNICODE_STRING` use `%wZ` - `swprintf(buffer, L"%wZ :: %wZ", Data1, Data2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

main error is

```
WriteFile(hFile, buffer, wcslen(buffer), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
```

`WriteFile` always take The number of **bytes** to be written to the file. but `wcslen` return the number of **characters** which in case UINICODE in 2 time less - need `* sizeof(WCHAR)` or `<< 1`

then for format `UNICODE_STRING` need use `%wZ` format - because in general case `Buffer` can be not 0 terminated. and better use `swprintf` or `_snwprintf` instead `wsprintf`.

at the last always better dynamic allocate needed buffer, then use hardcoded size, which can be overwritten

so i be use next code:

```
void test(PCUNICODE_STRING Data1, PCUNICODE_STRING Data2)
{
    DWORD dwBytesWritten;
    PWSTR buffer = (PWSTR)alloca(Data1->Length + Data2->Length + sizeof(L" :: \r\n"));
    int n = swprintf(buffer, L"%wZ :: %wZ\r\n", Data1, Data2) * sizeof(WCHAR);

    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(L"c:\\log.txt", FILE_APPEND_DATA, 0, NULL, 
        OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        WriteFile(hFile, buffer, n, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
        CloseHandle(hFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: @daisy - `alloca` allocated buffer in stack - it not need be free